# Digital Electronics Logical Word Problem

Tags: digital-logic

I am not able to come up with any solution formulation for this problem. Need Help!

***A student has to respond to an opinion poll by sending either ‘YES’, or ‘NO’ or ‘ABSTAIN’ through SMS. His decision will be based on the following considerations: (a) He will send ‘YES’ if that is his personal opinion and his parents agree with his opinion. (b) He will send ‘NO’ if that is his personal opinion and his parents agree with his opinion. (c) Otherwise, he will send ‘YES’ or ‘NO’ according to the majority opinion among his friends if there is a clear majority opinion and his parents also agree with that opinion. (d) He will send ‘ABSTAIN’ if he is unable to send either ‘YES’ or ‘NO’. Assign binary variables appropriately and obtain three separate logic expressions in terms of these variables for sending ‘YES’, ‘NO’ and ‘ABSTAIN’.***

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please realise this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Ask a specific question, showing your work and findings so far in considerable detail with any schematic. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Comment: I don't like riddles. Try asking your riddles on [Puzzling StackExchange](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It's actually pretty simple. You're going to send the parents' opinion unless both the student and his friends disagree with it, in which case, you send "Abstain".

Comment: @KingDuken: It isn't a riddle. It's a straightforward logic problem.

Comment: We don't just do your homework for you here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because homework must have an attempt at a solution

Answer (score 2):

1. Construct 3 K-maps for 3 outputs - YES, NO, ABSTAIN with 3 inputs : (Personal opinion,Parents opinion,Friends opinion)
2. There are only \$ 2^3 = 8\$  possibilities for inputs. Take '1' as 'YES' and '0' as 'NO' for inputs. For each possibility, the net result is either 'YES' or 'NO' or 'ABSTAIN'.
3. Fill all 3 K-maps accordingly and find the expressions for each.

Comment: You forgot about the requirement for a "clear majority" among the friends. There are actually four input variables.

Comment: But fourth one is redundant. Suppose many friends are there. Its alloted a third variable. If it is considered as a "1" or "YES" , it means its already majority.

Comment: But what does "0" mean? "Clear majority 'NO'" or "no clear majority"? There are *three* states you need to distinguish for the friends: Majority YES, majority NO, or equally-divided.

Comment: '0' means no clear majority so that means its equivalent to 'NO'.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Read the question more carefully!

Comment: If a variable for group of friends is assigned "1" ..it means it is already "majority of friends agree YES" ..likewise "0" means "NO"  ... so no point in a fourth variable to say again that majority of friends agreed to YES...

Comment: But what if the friends are equally divided on the opinion? According to section (c) of the question, you can't use that as a basis for sending Yes or No. In other words, you can't treat that as a "definite No" coming from the friends.

Comment: Then separate variable should be there for each friend. It seems unnecessary too.  Anyway Assigning a variable to a group of friends and a separate variable for majority are redundant .That's my point .

Answer (score -3):

There are four binary input variables:

- "S" - Student: yes/no
- "P" - Parents: yes/no
- "F" - Friends: yes/no
- "M" - Clear majority among friends: yes/no

There are three output possibilities (to be treated as one-hot):

- "Y" - send "Yes"
- "N" - send "No"
- "A" - send "Abstain"

Try to express the statements in the problem in terms of these variables.

For example, if S is asserted and P is asserted, then you can assert Y.

---

Since I don't seem to be making myself clear in [my conversation with Meenie Leis](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/372018/11683), here's the complete solution as I see it:

$$\begin{array}{cccc|ccc|l}
S&P&F&M&Y&N&A&\text{Comments}\\
\hline
0&0&-&-&0&1&0&\text{student and parents agree "No"}\\
1&1&-&-&1&0&0&\text{student and parents agree "Yes"}\\
-&0&0&1&0&1&0&\text{parents and friends agree "No"}\\
-&1&1&1&1&0&0&\text{parents and friends agree "Yes"}\\
0&1&-&0&0&0&1&\text{student and parents disagree, no majority among friends }\\
1&0&-&0&0&0&1&\text{student and parents disagree, no majority among friends }\\
0&1&0&1&0&0&1&\text{parents disagree with both student and friends}\\
1&0&1&1&0&0&1&\text{parents disagree with both student and friends}\\
\end{array}$$

Since the 3rd and 4th lines give different results, you clearly cannont combine F and M into a single variable.